# Python transform dict recursively based on predefined mappings

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I have a use case where I need to traverse a dict (which could have strings, dicts and lists as nested values) and create a new one based on predefined mappings by my business team. My first implementation was straightforward when the requirements were:

1. 1:1 transformations
2. drop some key value pairs

My code looked something like this:

```
def recursively_transform(parent_keys='', current_key='', container=None):
    container_class = container.__class__
    new_container_value = None
    if container is not None:
        if isinstance(container, basestring):
            new_container_value = do_something_and_return(parent_keys, current_key, container)
            if current_key in mapping:
                populate(parent_keys + current_key, new_container_value)
        elif isinstance(container, collections.Mapping):
            if parent_keys:
                parent_keys = ''.join([parent_keys, ":"])
            new_container_value = container_class(
                (x, recursively_transform(parent_keys + x, x, container[x])) for x in container if key_required(parent_keys, current_key))
        elif isinstance(container, collections.Iterable):
            new_container_value = container_class(recursively_transform(
                parent_keys + "[]", current_key, x) for x in container)
        else:
            raise Exception("")
    return new_container_value
```

As you can see, within the method `do_something_and_return`, using the parameters `parent_key` and `current_key`, I do some transformation on the value and return new one. The steps for each `parent_keys` plus `current_key` combination is specified in an external mappings database.

But, now, the requirement has changed to have complex transformations (not 1:1 anymore). i.e, inside my mappings database, the new path for the key will be specified. This could be any structure. For eg, key/value pairs have to be flattened, many times the reverse has to happen, sometimes there wouldn't be any direct correspondence between them.

Examples,

```
key1:key2:[]:key3 => key2:[]:key3
key1:key2:[]:key4 => key2:[]:key5
```

which means that an input dict like this:

```
{key1:{key2:[{key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}, {key3:None}]}}
```

would become

```
{key2:[{key3:"value3_after_transformation", key5:"value4_after_transformation"}, {key3:None}]}
```

`:` is a separator in my descriptive language for parent key and child key, `[]` infers that the parent key has a list as its value.

I am confused as to what should the approach be in this case. The only approach I can think of to handle all these cases is to traverse all the keys recursively and then populate another global dict on the fly by checking for the existence of target keys and populating them appropriately. But this is not easy when it comes to dealing with nested lists. Also, this doesn't sound an elegant solution like I have above using containers and their children. What is the best approach to do this in a generalistic way and in an elegant manner?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not exactly clear what are you trying to achieve but based on your writing it seems that you're looking for a descriptive language to traverse dictionaries and there are various modules, mostly from the JSON-Path family, dedicated to exactly that. Have you considered something like [`JMESPath`](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py)?

Comment: I am not looking for a descriptive language to traverse, instead I want to roll out my own version which would traverse an input dict (or JSON) and create a new one with path changes as per the mappings database created by my BA team.

Comment: @zwer let me know if I am still not clear. I've added examples to help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I succeed. This passes your given testcases, but it is very long. It finds all possible path for a given template and then populates a new dict according to the new paths

```
 import re


def prepare_path(path):
    # split path
    path = re.findall(r"[^:]+?(?=\[|:|$)|\[\d*?\]", path)
    # prepare path
    for i, element in enumerate(path):
        if element[0] == "[" and element[-1] == "]":
            element = int(element[1:-1])
        path[i] = element
    return path


def prepare_template(template):
    # split path template
    template = re.findall(r"[^:]+?(?=\[|:|$)|\[\d*?\]", template)
    # prepare path template
    counter = 0
    for i, element in enumerate(template):
        if element[0] == "[" and element[-1] == "]":
            if len(element) > 2:
                element = int(element[1:-1])
            else:
                element = ("ListIndex", counter)
        template[i] = element
    return template


def fill_template(template, list_indexes):
    out = []
    for element in template:
        if isinstance(element, tuple):
            element = f"[{list_indexes[element[1]]}]"
        out.append(element)
    return ":".join(out)


def populate(result_dict, target_path, value):
    target_path = prepare_path(target_path)
    current = result_dict
    for i, element in enumerate(target_path[:-1]):
        if isinstance(element, str):  # dict index
            if element not in current:  # create new entry
                if isinstance(target_path[i + 1], str):  # next is a dict
                    current[element] = {}
                else:  # next is a list
                    current[element] = []
        elif isinstance(element, int):  # list index
            if element >= len(current):  # create new entry
                current.extend(None for _ in range(element - len(current) + 1))
            if current[element] is None:
                if isinstance(target_path[i + 1], str):  # next is a dict
                    current[element] = {}
                else:  # next is a list
                    current[element] = []
        current = current[element]
    if isinstance(target_path[-1], int):
        current.append(value)
    else:
        current[target_path[-1]] = value


def get_value(container, target_path):
    target_path = prepare_path(target_path)
    current = container
    for key in target_path:
        current = current[key]
    return current


def transform(old_path, new_path, old_container, new_container, transform_value=lambda *args: ' '.join(args)):
    value = get_value(old_container, old_path)
    new_value = transform_value(old_path, new_path, value)
    populate(new_container, new_path, new_value)


def get_all_paths(prepared_template, container):
    if not prepared_template:
        return [("",())]
    key, *rest = prepared_template
    if isinstance(key, tuple):
        if not isinstance(container, list):
            raise ValueError(container, key)
        paths = [(f"[{i}]:" + path, (i,) + per) for i, child in enumerate(container) for path, per in get_all_paths(rest, child)]
    elif isinstance(key, str):
        if key not in container:
            return []
        child = container[key]
        paths = [(f"{key}:" + path, per) for path, per in get_all_paths(rest, child)]
    elif isinstance(key, int):
        child = container[key]
        paths = [(f"[{key}]:" + path, per) for path, per in get_all_paths(rest, child)]
    else:
        raise ValueError
    return paths


def transform_all(old_template, new_template, old_container, new_container, transform_value=lambda op, np, value: value):
    new_template = prepare_template(new_template)
    old_template = prepare_template(old_template)
    all_paths = get_all_paths(old_template, old_container)
    for path, per in all_paths:
        transform(path, fill_template(new_template, per), old_container, new_container, transform_value)

input_dict = {"key1": {"key2": [{"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}, {"key3": None}]}}
output_dict = {}
transform_all("key1:key2:[]:key3", "key2:[]:key3", input_dict, output_dict)
transform_all("key1:key2:[]:key4", "key2:[]:key5", input_dict, output_dict)
print(output_dict)
```

If you have any questions or other situations that fail, ask! These are fun challenges you are giving us.